# `dict.popitem` with filtered data and a conditional flag

Tags: python

I am implementing a something that uses a dictionary to store data. Additionally to the normal data, it also stores some internal data, all prefixed with `_`. However, I want to isolate the user of the library from this data since he is normally not concerned with it. Additionally, I need to set a `modified` flag in my class to track if the data was modified.

For all interface functions this worked nicely, here are two examples, one with and one without modification. Note that in this case, I do not hide internal data, because it is intentionally demanded as a key:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self._data[key]

def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    self.modified = True
    self._data[key] = value
```

On some functions, e.g. `__iter__`, I filter out everything that starts with `_` before I yield the data.

But a single function makes real problems here: `popitem`. In its normal behaviour it would just withdraw an arbitrary item and return it while deleting it from the dict. However, here comes the problem: Without deep internal knowledge, I don't know which item will be returned beforehand. But I know that `popitem` follows the same rules as `items` and `keys`. So I did come up with an implementation:

```
keys = self._data.keys()
for k in keys:
    if k.startswith("_"):
        continue
    v = self._data.pop(k)
    self.modified = True
    return k, v
else:
    raise KeyError('popitem(): dictionary is empty')
```

This implementation works. But it feels to unpythonic and not at all dynamic or clean. It did also struggle with the idea to raise the exception like this: `{}.popitem()` which looks totally insane but would give me at least a dynamic way (e.g. if the exception message or type ever changes, I don't have to adjust).

What I am now after is a cleaner and less crazy way to solve this problem. There would be a way of removing the internal data from the dict, but I'd only take this road as a last resort. So do you have any recipes or ideas for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your objects *two* dict attributes: `self._data` and `self._internal_data`.  Then forward all the dict methods to `self._data`, and you won't have to filter out anything.

edit: Okay, I missed the "last resort" bit at the end.  But I suspect that managing two dicts will be far easier than "fixing" every single dict method and operator.  :)

Comment: If you want to do this, then subclass `dict` and implement `__missing__()` so that it looks up items in the second dict when it fails to find them in the first.

Comment: @kindall or possibly look at `ChainMap`

Comment: @kindall doesn't that defeat the point?  i'm not actually sure why this data is all stored in the same dict in the first place when the OP is going to such lengths to hide it all.

Comment: @Eevee The OP states he wants the data to be available if the exact name is requested but not when iterating, popping, etc.

Comment: @kindall whoops, missed that paragraph entirely.  checking both in `__getitem__` is simplest by far then.

Comment: `__missing__` is even simpler, since you don't need an `if`.

Comment: That is **awesome**. Through a combination of using two distinct dicts and persisting them as a tuple and applying `__missing__` and `UserDict` with some additional tweaks required for this case, I got a way simpler solution working.

Answer (score 1):

1. Subclass `dict` rather than wrapping a dictionary. You'll need to implement a lot less stuff.
2. Store your "internal data" as attributes on the object, not in the dictionary. This way they are easy to get to if you need them, but won't appear in ordinary iteration. If at some point you need to combine them, do that with `x = dict(self); x.update(self.__dict__)` to create a new dictionary having both sets of values.

If you do want to store your internal data as a dictionary, embed that one. Implement `__missing__` on your main object so you can grab items from the internal dictionary if they're not found in the main one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the logic's correct, you could reduce it to something like:

```
self._data.pop(next((key for key in self._data if not key.startswith('_')), 'popitem(): dictionary is empty'))
```

So, find the next key in `self._data` that doesn't start with `_`, otherwise default it to a key that isn't going to match any of the other keys in the dictionary so that when the pop fails, you automatically get the `KeyError` thrown (with your "error message")